# Bootstrap 4 - Nested columns - Fitting 4 columns inside col-11

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to fit 4 columns inside a col-11 but these get stacked vertically. Can someone help me correct/explain this behavior? Here is the code and codepen example of the same:

[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEyyOp](http://Codepen%20URL:%20col-3%20inside%20col-11)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid no-gutters">

        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-1">PHASES</div>
            <div class="col-11 no-gutters">
                <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DISCOVER</div>
                <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DESIGN</div>
                <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DELIVER</div>
                <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DEPLOY</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just need a `row` inside your `col-11`:

```
<div class="col-11 no-gutters">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DISCOVER</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DESIGN</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DELIVER</div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">DEPLOY</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MPrQVa

Comment: Thanks Tim. That worked for me.

Comment: No problem. Check the question marked as duplicate as well, explains what's happening. I didn't know this about bootstrap 4, but apparently "*In Bootstrap 4, `.col-` that are not placed in `.row` will stack vertically.*"